# How to create a share on a remote computer and copy files to that share on Windows?

Tags: windows, network-shares

I'm building a script that will run WatiN, a tool that makes Web Application Testing possible, on a remote machine. I won't go in to any details, but the scripts does the following:

- Create a network-share on the remote client machine (Windows 7)
- Copy a runner to the remote machine
- Create a test database on an other server
- Copy the web-application to a webserver
- Start the runner on the remote machine
- Copy the results back to the current machine
- Clean-up the remote machine

To do stuff on the remote machine I use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), this works fine and in fact the script runs fine except one step, the first.

The problem is that the network-share that I have created on the remote machine is read-only. With PsExec I run the following script on the remote machine:

```
net share WatiN=C:\RemoteWatin /GRANT:Everyone, FULL
```

The grant doesn't work, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had no rights to GRANT Everyone FULL control, but it does work when I grant myself full control.

Here's my working command:

```
net share WatiN-%1=C:\RemoteWatin\%1 /GRANT:%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%,FULL
```